# multiple instances of animated object

Tags: instances

I created an animated object that consists of several pieces. now I would like to have multiple instances of it, but instead of them all being in sync I want to be able to manipulate the keyframes individually.

I read about `group instances`, which allow editing the original object, with all the changes being propagated to the instances. that's what I want, but there doesn't seem to be a way to change the animation per instance.

the alternative is to create a `linked duplicate`. here the animation *can* be changed per instance, but any changes to the model will not be propagated.

[image]

what if I want both? — is there a way to have the geometry linked, but the animation data local to the object?